# Executing all clauses and deleting somes

Tags: prolog

I guess this is an easy question,but I am quite newbie to Prolog.

My problem is : I have a predicate as input, let's call it InputPredicate : `father(Paul, john).`

I have a knowledge base with these predicates :

```
stim(mother(jean, sam), [delete]) :-
   prove_things(jean),
   prove_something_else(sam).
stim(father(paul, rob), []) :-
   prove_another_thing(rob).
stim(father(paul, X), [delete]) :-
   prove_something_else(X).
stim(father(paul, john), []) :-
   prove_another_thing(paul).
stim(father(david, henry), []) :-
   another_predicate(david).
```

My question is: how to find the best/fastest way to prove all clauses that match : `stim(InputPredicate, Options)` and retract some matching clauses, if `delete` is among `Options` list ?

I have tried something like :

```
execute(InputPredicate) :-   
  stim(InputPredicate, Options),   
  delete_stim_if_needed(InputPredicate, Options),   
  fail. 
execute(_).

delete_stim_if_needed(InputPredicate, Options) :-
  member(delete, Options),
  retract(( InputPredicate :- ????? )).
delete_stim(_, _).
```

but as you can see, I don't know how to get the body of the clause to retract, to retract it ?

I am using a very basic prolog ( [Erlog](https://github.com/rvirding/erlog) ) and there are some predicates not implemented (`bagoff` for exemple), but `findall/3`,`clause/2` are available.

I made also an attempts with `findall` but I am finally facing same issue... may be by combining `findall/3` and `clause/2` ?

Thank you for any help advice or for reading,

Yan

Comment: So far, I do not understand your question. What do you want? A definition of a predicate with how many arguments and that does what exactly? Then please write an example question and describe what the Prolog system is supposed answer and also, how its database should be altered thereafter, if that's what you are aiming at.

Comment: My question is in the body ^^
```I would like to find the best/fastest way to execute all clauses that match : stim(InputPredicate, Options), so here, that would match stim(father(paul, john), Options) and retract this clause, and all matching ones if delete is among Options```

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by "execute".

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is a failure-driven loop.

Comment: sorry, I meant prove all clauses that match.


I have tried something like :
`execute(InputPredicate) :-
  stim(InputPredicate, Options),
  delete_stim_if_needed(InputPredicate, Options),
  fail.
execute(_).`


But I just don't see how to retract only the matching clause, I think I need the body of the clause to use into retract/1 ifI want to remove it from knowledge base ? 
`retract(( InputPredicate :- Body))`

Comment: please add that to your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to have a predicate that takes a structure as argument and that should do two things:

1. call **all** goals matching  stim(Structure, _)
2. delete all clauses headed by `stim(Structure, Options)`, where `delete` is a member of Options from the database.

First of all, you need stim to be dynamic, otherwise clauses can't be dynamically added to/deleted from the database:

```
:- dynamic stim/2.
```

Then this predicate will do the job:

```
execute(Structure) :-   
\+execute2(Structure),
\+special_delete(Structure).

execute2(Structure) :-   
   stim(Structure, _),   
   fail. 

special_delete(Structure) :-
   Head = stim(Structure, Options),
   clause(Head, Body),
   member(delete, Options),
   retract(:-(Head, Body)),
   fail.
```

This is another solution:

```
execute(Structure) :-   \+execute1(Structure).
  
execute1(Structure) :-   
   Goal = stim(Structure, Options),
   clause(Goal, Body),
   \+execute2(Goal),
   member(delete, Options),
   retract(:-(Goal, Body)),
   fail.

execute2(Goal) :-  Goal, fail.
```

Both solutions want to make sure that a goal `stim(Structure,Options)` can be proven more than once.

If that is not necessary (because the relevant goals can be proven exactly once) or not wanted (because the clause needs to be deleted after the first proof of its head), then this is an alternative solution:

```
execute(Structure) :-   \+execute1(Structure).

execute1(Structure) :-   
   Goal = stim(Structure, Options),
   clause(Goal, Body),
   Goal,
   member(delete, Options),
   retract(:-(Goal, Body)),
   fail.
```

Comment: Yes, first part would do the job :)
Regarding second point, I would prove clause 1 and clause 2 but delete clause 1 only.

Comment: That could be done shorter, depending on how often the respective goals can be proven and whyt the expected behaviour is in these cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot tiffi, it made the job !
Ideally I would like to delete the clause right after proving it, but I think I can manage this by myself.
So thanks again for your clarifications and solution.

Comment: Thanks for completing. I will go for third solution as indeed I want to prove each clause once, and have it deleted right after.
Loos almost easy now I look at the solution. Thks++